# Setting a variable but php is just ignoring it and overwriting it?

Tags: php

Okay, so, I have a `configuration.php`, and in there I have this:
`$baseURL = 'http://www.website.com';` (just hiding my site)

On every page I call the `configuration.php`, and it doesn't matter what directory or page I'm on (yes I'm setting the `configuration.php` to the correct directory) but I try to make a image link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/images/logo.png"></a>
```

So that should, when clicked, take me to `http://www.website.com`. Nope, it takes me to the same page. It's like its overwriting itself... I have nothing overwriting it in my code, it just like sets itself to the current page instead of just `http://www.website.com`

Comment: If the link is taking you to the same page it means that $baseUrl is either falsy or undefined. Try echoing something out in your configuration.php to see if is being included properly.

Comment: There are many aspects to check here.... 1. take care to clear your browser cache between attempts. Then: there is no need for such absolute URLs in links. Have a try with relative path instead, that makes your code more portable anyway. Then: check what is actually contained inside the links you generate, try using right click inside your browser and chosing "inspect element" in the menu. Also check for entries in your http servers error log file, that is where php logs runtime errors to. I expect your links to be empty, btw, reading your description...

Comment: How are you calling the configuration file in?

I agree with the other commenter that if you use relative links effectively, you shouldn't need to explicitly declare the site domain.

If you want to display a link to be copied (like a perma-link to an article or blog post) then you can use an environment variable.

Comment: use a `firebug` in firefox to see if `href` is being set as desired. Cant you replace `<?php echo $baseURL; ?>` with `/` in `a` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have a config file to declare the value, and by call, I'm guessing you mean include. If you're not using include, could you tell us what you're doing? More code!

config.php

```
<? $baseURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>
```

Then

```
<? include "config.php"; ?>
<a href="<? echo $baseURL; ?>"><img src="<? echo $baseURL; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo.png"><? echo $baseURL; ?></a>
```

Also check for error_log entries related to this, you may find that it tells you exactly what is wrong.